# concrete5 installation on openshift

Tags: php, git, cloud, openshift, concrete5

I am encountering several problems while trying to deploy a default installation with sample data of the latest version of concrete5 - 5.7.3.1

Can somebody help me, and post a working example of webhooks etc, that allows persistence of the user uploaded data etc?

I've had only a partial success, and each time I re-push git some files reset and I am back at the installation screen.

I have also noticed with the demo installation the color customization won't work.

I suppose I need extra writing permissions other than only the 3 folders requested at installation.?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have multiple questions in one here, but I can pitch in and maybe point you in the right direction for part of it...

Not having used openshift before, I don't have a solid grasp on the issues your running into, but look at the discussion here about [running C5 in ephemeral environments](https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5-5.7.0/issues/1861#issuecomment-83187474).

To give you a concrete answer to your question, if your directories don't have writable permission out of the gate, you have to do some hackage to get it to run. Work is being done so that C5 won't rely on writing config values at runtime to flat file storage as thats not an ideal solution in the first place, but it takes a little know how to get around it.

Specifically, you can override the cache store settings in application/config/concrete.php, and force C5 to use something more appropriate (eg. redis, memcache, etc). Gist here with a sample file on how to do so: https://gist.github.com/jhartman86/ab1d7100cdee3dc520cf.

If you provide more details on the exact problems you're running into it will help to get to the root of the issues more effectively.